# Node.js json fetching

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am fetching JSON data from `instagram api`, which return something like `{"pagination": {}, "data": [{"id": ......` and I am using node.js to fetch it. What's wrong with my code? I cannot see the expected console log of 'success'!

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    request = require('request'),
    url = require('url');

var results = [];

var target = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=';

request.get(target, function(error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('data').each(function(i, element) {
      console.log('success');
        results.push(element);
    });

    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(error)` and `console.log($)`?

Comment: null for (error)

Comment: for ($),
{ [Function: initialize]
  fn:
   initialize {
     constructor: [Circular],
     _originalRoot:
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Array],
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null } },
  load: [Function],
  html: [Function],
  xml: [Function],
  text: [Function],
  parseHTML: [Function],
  root: [Function],
  contains: [Function],
  merge: [Function],
  _root:

Comment: Oops that should have been `console.log($('data'))`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use cheerio instead of doing a `JSON.parse(body)`?

Comment: I am required to use cheerio

Comment: console.log($('data'))
initialize {
  options:
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xml: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root:
   initialize {
     '0':
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Array],
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null },
     options:
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,

Comment: The problem is cheerio is a tool for dealing with HTML but you have JSON.  Look at the raw data returned from the URL.  You should be required to use the right tool for the job.  Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
request.get(target, function(error, response, body) {

    console.log(body);

    // you can get pagination, etc with yourObj.pagination, ...
    var yourObj = JSON.parse(body);
});
```